# Iteration of list with filtering condition

Tags: python, list

I have two lists (starting_year,ending_year) as below, and I want to iterate both list in such that it will return me a possible combination of starting_year and ending_year. However, I want to filter out any combination that doesn't make any sense, example of those value is; starting year that is greater than ending year, ex (2015,2014) or starting year = ending year (2014,2014).

I know it sound simple, but anyone knows how to write it?

```
starting_year=[2012,2013,2014,2015]
ending_year=[2015,2014,2013,2012]

for i in range (0,len(starting_year)):
    for j in range (0,len(ending_year)):
        print(starting_year[i],ending_year[j])
```

current output

```
2012 2015
2012 2014
2012 2013
2012 2012
2013 2015
2013 2014
2013 2013
2013 2012
2014 2015
2014 2014
2014 2013
2014 2012
2015 2015
2015 2014
2015 2013
2015 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate on the values and add a condition:

```
starting_year = [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]
ending_year = [2015, 2014, 2013, 2012]

for i in starting_year:
    for j in ending_year:
        if i < j:
            print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
2012 2015
2012 2014
2012 2013
2013 2015
2013 2014
2014 2015
```